# lock table syntax from mysql to oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

I've a mysql sql locking some tables with different permission (read  or write).
I've to adapt it for oracle, but I did't found any clear documentation to do this job right.

this is an example:

```
LOCK TABLE  
alpha  read, 
beta write, 
beta as tb read, 
gamma write,
delta read
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to lock these tables?  What is the problem you are trying to solve?

In Oracle, it is exceptionally rare that you actually need to acquire an explicit lock on a table.  And in Oracle, it is impossible to lock a table in a way that prevents other sessions from reading the data in the table.  It does not appear that you'll be able to map this directly into Oracle because you cannot block readers.

The [lock table syntax](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems027.htm) in Oracle is relatively similar to the syntax in MySQL.  You could, for example

```
LOCK TABLE alpha IN row exclusive mode;
```

But it is not clear whether this is going to really solve whatever problem you're facing.

Comment: I'm porting a web application using mysql to oracle.

Comment: It's clear to me that this massive use of lock it's insane, but I've to in order to replicate the logic used since now.

Comment: An important follow up.

In MySql, once you start a lock statement, you must lock every table you query/modify before the release of the lock.
That's explain the **huge** lock statement I write in the example.

Comment: @Ivan - Note that some of this logic simply cannot be replicated in Oracle.  As I said in my reply, it is impossible in Oracle to lock a table in a way that prevents other sessions from reading the data in that table.  If your application depends on blocking readers, you need to fundamentally reconsider your locking scheme in Oracle.